# ExpressJs View helpers do not work

Tags: node.js, express

It's probably a newbie question. I'm trying to setup my very first expressjs application and I need to use a view helpers that doesn't work for some reason.

Here is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var test = function(req, res, next) {
    res.myLog = function(){
        console.log("res");
        return "Hello";
    }
    next();
}

app.use(test);
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./dist/index.html');
})

app.listen(5000);
```

And index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test application</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
        <script src='<%=myLog()%>'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Yo World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

myLog function is not call during rendering. Originally I was trying to use some third part helpers and they didn't work as well.

I haven't found any documentation of how to use the helpers on expressjs site. I'm clearly doing something wrong here.

Express version 4.3.14

Answer (score 0):

To send file using `express`, correct ways is:

```
//sending html files
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// viewed at http://localhost:5000
app.get('/', showClientRequest, function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

function showClientRequest(req, res, next) {
    var request = {
        REQUEST : {
            HEADERS: req.headers,
            BODY : req.body
        }
    }
    console.log(request)
    return next();
}

app.listen(5000);
```

Use ejs template engine:

```
var express = require('express');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var path = require('path');

// viewed at http://localhost:5000
app.get('/', showClientRequest, function(req, res) {
    res.render('index',{message:"Hello World!"});
});

function showClientRequest(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Something Here...');
    return next();
}

app.listen(5000);
```

**Node-Cheat Available:**

For complete code, get working node-cheat at [express_server](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/random/small_tasks/express_server) run `node app` followed by `npm install express ejs`.

Comment: It's still doesn't handle <%=myLog%> correctly. It just ignores it.

Comment: @lostaman see updated answer, both solutions are provided to clear your concept. You can use ejs engine for your purpose. Please mark answer correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `res.locals.myLog` instead of `res.myLog` to set locals. If you don't need `req` within your helper function you can also use `app.locals.myLog`.

`res.sendfile` will not render your view but just send a file as it is. You will have to use `res.render` and move your `dist/index.html` to `views/index.ejs`.